# SAPUI5 mockserver.js start multiple server

Tags: sapui5

I am working with SAPUI5 and trying to mock the backend OData service. Now as per the example I can see we can start a mock server with single OData service but in our project, we are dealing with multiple OData services and I want to mock them all. Is it really possible to do that or not that is my first question? I am thinking of modifying the mockserver.js file as mentioned below but not sure if this is going to work and that's why I am here asking this question.

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/util/MockServer"
], function (MockServer) {
    "use strict";
    return {
        init: function () {
            // create
            var oMockServer = new MockServer({
                rootUri: "https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/"
            }); 
            var oUriParameters = jQuery.sap.getUriParameters();
            // configure
            MockServer.config({
                autoRespond: true,
                autoRespondAfter: oUriParameters.get("serverDelay") || 1000
            });
            // simulate
            var sPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("sap.ui.demo.walkthrough.localService");
            oMockServer.simulate(sPath + "/metadata.xml", sPath + "/mockdata");


            //mockserver number 2
            var oMockServer2 = new MockServer({
                rootUri: "https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind2/Northwind2.svc/"
            }); 
            var oUriParameters2 = jQuery.sap.getUriParameters();
            // configure
            MockServer.config({
                autoRespond: true,
                autoRespondAfter: oUriParameters2.get("serverDelay") || 1000
            });
            // simulate
            var sPath2 = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("sap.ui.demo.walkthrough.localService");
            oMockServer2.simulate(sPath + "/metadata2.xml", sPath + "/mockdata2");


            // start
            oMockServer.start();
            oMockServer2.start();
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Basically it should be possible to run whatever number of mock servers. Did you try it? If yes - what is not working? Did not get a point from your question.

Comment: I just tried it and it is working. Is it a recommended way to test SAPUI5 app with multiple odata services?

Comment: No, this is not recommended from SAP: see the golden rule 8 : https://blogs.sap.com/2015/11/17/best-build-own-freestyle-sap-fiori-apps-for-fiori-launchpad-10-golden-rules/.

Comment: But sometimes we are forced to break them, I don't see any issues with that :)

Comment: Thanks, Andril, it is good that you have provided me with the golden rules. Can you also have a quick look at my answer?

Comment: If it works then it is fine. I do not see any issues.

Comment: Yes it is working fine no issues so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have tested the approach with multiple mock servers and it is working. Now I am not sure if this is a valid approach, however, I am sharing my final mockserver.js file.

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/util/MockServer"
], function (MockServer) {
    "use strict";
    return {
        init: function () {
            // create
            const oMockServer = new MockServer({
                rootUri: "/destinations/northwind/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/"
            });
            const oUriParameters = jQuery.sap.getUriParameters();
            // configure
            MockServer.config({
                autoRespond: true,
                autoRespondAfter: oUriParameters.get("serverDelay") || 1000
            });
            // simulate
            const sPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("worklist.localService");

            oMockServer.simulate(sPath + "/metadata.xml", sPath + "/mockdata");

            const oMockServer2 = new MockServer({
                rootUri: "/destinations/northwind/V2/Northwind/NorthwindC.svc/"
            });
            const oUriParameters2 = jQuery.sap.getUriParameters();
            // configure
            MockServer.config({
                autoRespond: true,
                autoRespondAfter: oUriParameters2.get("serverDelay") || 1000
            });
            // simulate
            const sPath2 = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("worklist.localService");

            oMockServer2.simulate(sPath2 + "/metadata2.xml", sPath2 + "/mockdata");

            // start
            oMockServer.start();
            oMockServer2.start();
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I extended the auto generated `mockserver.js` like the following:

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/util/MockServer",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/base/util/UriParameters",
    "sap/base/Log"
], function (MockServer, JSONModel, UriParameters, Log) {
    "use strict";

    var aMockServers = [],
        _sAppPath = "com/mjzsoft/APP_Name/",
        _sJsonFilesPath = _sAppPath + "localService/mockdata";

    var oMockServerInterface = {

        /**
         * Initializes the mock server asynchronously.
         * You can configure the delay with the URL parameter "serverDelay".
         * The local mock data in this folder is returned instead of the real data for testing.
         * @protected
         * @param {object} [oOptionsParameter] init parameters for the mockserver
         * @returns{Promise} a promise that is resolved when the mock server has been started
         */
        init: function (oOptionsParameter) {
            var oOptions = oOptionsParameter || {};

            return new Promise(function (fnResolve, fnReject) {
                var sManifestUrl = sap.ui.require.toUrl(_sAppPath + "manifest.json"),
                    oManifestModel = new JSONModel(sManifestUrl);

                oManifestModel.attachRequestCompleted(function () {
                    var oUriParameters = new UriParameters(window.location.href),
                        // parse manifest for local metatadata URI
                        sJsonFilesUrl = sap.ui.require.toUrl(_sJsonFilesPath);
                        var oData = oManifestModel.getData();
                    var serviceList = Object.values(oData["sap.app"].dataSources);

                    for (var i = 0; i < serviceList.length; i++) {
                        var oMainDataSource = serviceList[i];

                        if (oMainDataSource.type === "OData") {
                            var sMetadataUrl = sap.ui.require.toUrl(_sAppPath + oMainDataSource.settings.localUri),
                                // ensure there is a trailing slash
                                sMockServerUrl = /.*\/$/.test(oMainDataSource.uri) ? oMainDataSource.uri : oMainDataSource.uri + "/";
                            // ensure the URL to be relative to the application
                            sMockServerUrl = sMockServerUrl && new URI(sMockServerUrl).absoluteTo(sap.ui.require.toUrl(_sAppPath)).toString();

                            // create a mock server instance or stop the existing one to reinitialize
                            if (!aMockServers[oMainDataSource.uri]) {
                                aMockServers[oMainDataSource.uri] = new MockServer({
                                    rootUri: sMockServerUrl
                                });
                            } else {
                                aMockServers[oMainDataSource.uri].stop();
                            }

                            // configure mock server with the given options or a default delay of 0.5s
                            MockServer.config({
                                autoRespond: true,
                                autoRespondAfter: (oOptions.delay || oUriParameters.get("serverDelay") || 500)
                            });

                            // simulate all requests using mock data
                            aMockServers[oMainDataSource.uri].simulate(sMetadataUrl, {
                                sMockdataBaseUrl: sJsonFilesUrl,
                                bGenerateMissingMockData: true
                            });

                            var aRequests = aMockServers[oMainDataSource.uri].getRequests();

                            // compose an error response for each request
                            var fnResponse = function (iErrCode, sMessage, aRequest) {
                                aRequest.response = function (oXhr) {
                                    oXhr.respond(iErrCode, {
                                        "Content-Type": "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
                                    }, sMessage);
                                };
                            };

                            // simulate metadata errors
                            if (oOptions.metadataError || oUriParameters.get("metadataError")) {
                                aRequests.forEach(function (aEntry) {
                                    if (aEntry.path.toString().indexOf("$metadata") > -1) {
                                        fnResponse(500, "metadata Error", aEntry);
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            // simulate request errors
                            var sErrorParam = oOptions.errorType || oUriParameters.get("errorType"),
                                iErrorCode = sErrorParam === "badRequest" ? 400 : 500;
                            if (sErrorParam) {
                                aRequests.forEach(function (aEntry) {
                                    fnResponse(iErrorCode, sErrorParam, aEntry);
                                });
                            }

                            // custom mock behaviour may be added here
                            // custom mock behaviour may be added here
                            aMockServers[oMainDataSource.uri].attachBefore("GET", function (oEvent) {
                                console.log(oEvent); // eslint-disable-line
                            });
                            aMockServers[oMainDataSource.uri].attachBefore("POST", function (oEvent) {
                                console.log(oEvent); // eslint-disable-line
                            });
                            // set requests and start the server
                            aMockServers[oMainDataSource.uri].setRequests(aRequests);
                            aMockServers[oMainDataSource.uri].start();
                        }
                    }

                    Log.info("Running the app with mock data");
                    fnResolve();
                });

                oManifestModel.attachRequestFailed(function () {
                    var sError = "Failed to load application manifest";

                    Log.error(sError);
                    fnReject(new Error(sError));
                });
            });
        },

        /**
         * @public returns the mockserver of the app, should be used in integration tests
         * @param {string} id the name of the related dataset 
         * @returns {sap.ui.core.util.MockServer} the mockserver instance
         */
        getMockServer: function (id) {
            return aMockServers[id];
        }
    };

    return oMockServerInterface;
});
```

It reads the `manifest.json` and generates mock servers for all resources of type `OData`!